# Random sets and invariant extensions of Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

1. Given AC, is there a probability measure $\mu$ on $2^{[0,1]}$ and a translation-invariant extension $\lambda$ of Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ such that: for all permutations $\pi$ of $[0,1]$ and all Lebesgue measurable $B\subseteq[0,1]$, for $\mu$-almost all $A\subseteq [0,1]$, we have $\pi[A]$ $\lambda$-measurable and $\lambda(\pi[A]\cap B)=(1/2)\lambda(B)$?
2. If not, what if we drop "translation-invariant" and/or "$\lambda(\pi[A]\cap B)=(1/2)\lambda(B)$"? (OK, that's three questions, then.)

Comment: What is a "permutation of $[0,1]$"? Any bijection from $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]$? In that case, if the equality were to hold for one $A$ then it would hold for all $A$ of the same cardinality for which $[0,1]\setminus A$ has the same cardinality --- that's not possible.

Comment: Yes, any bijection from $[0,1]$ to itself is a permutation. But I don't see why if equality were to hold for one $A$ then it would hold for all $A$ of the same cardinality and co-cardinality. Note the order of quantifiers: first $\pi$ is fixed, and then the equality holds for $\mu$-almost all $A$.